# How do I migrate a Windows 2008 Domain Controller to another computer?

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, domain-controller

I have single server acting as a domain controller. It is running Windows 2008 Standard edition. What steps are required to migrate this domain to another computer running Windows 2008? I'd like a detailed list of all the steps required and any gotchas.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- DC Promo the new server to join the existing domain, wait for al AD data to replicate
- If DNS is installed on the old server, install on the new one. Create an AD integrated zone for your domain DNS data and wait for it to replicate
- Transfer any other roles such as DHCP, WINS etc.
- [Transfer all FSMO roles](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/324801) to the new server. (I realise the article is for server 2003 however the process is the same
- Turn of old server and check clients can login and perform all required tasks
- Leave old server turned of but ready for use should a problem occur, for a reasonable period of time, usually a couple of weeks to a month

Comment: And finally, before the 60-day tombstone interval, use DCPromo on the old domain controller to remove it.  It would also be *highly* recommended to add a second permanent domain controller (possibly virtual) sometime soon.

Comment: Just to be picky: If there is already an AD Integrated zone in the domain/forest, it will automatically show up in DNS as soon as you install the DNS Service on your new server (depending a bit on replication config, but in a default config it will replicate automatically)

Answer (score 1):

Isn't it as simple as adding a second domain controller then transferring  all the FSMO roles to the new DC?
Not knowing all the details you may have dependant roles than need transferring like dns DHCP etc